# Trying to understand definition of weak topology on normed vector spaces

Tags: normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, dual-spaces, locally-convex-spaces, weak-topology

Given a normed vector space $X$ and $f\in X^{\ast}$ (=dual space of $X$), we define a seminorm on $X$ by $$p_{f}(x):=|f(x)|$$ for all $x\in X$. The book *"A Course in Functional Analysis (second edition)"* written by *"John B. Conway"* defines the weak topology on $X$ using the fact that the family $$\mathscr{P}:=\{p_{f} \ | \ f\in X^{\ast}\}$$ of seminorms is separable, i.e. $$\bigcap_{f\in X^{\ast}}p_{f}^{-1}[\{0\}]=\{0_{X}\},$$ or, equivalently,  $$\forall x\in X\setminus\{0_{X}\}, \ \exists x^{\ast}\in X^{\ast}, \ p_{x^{\ast}}(x)>0.$$ However, I don't see why this is true. I heard that it can be shown by the [Hahn-Banach theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn%E2%80%93Banach_theorem), but I have no idea where to start. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your intersection is the intersection of all kernels of linear functionals. It is $0$ if and only if you have that for any $x\in X$ there is a functional $f\in X^*$ so that $f(x)\neq0$. Can you see how Hahn-Banach helps you here?

Comment: No sorry, I dont see it. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Hahn Banach says that if $V\subseteq X$ is a subspace and $f : V\to \Bbb C$ is a continuous linear functional, then there exists a functional $\tilde  f : X\to \Bbb C$ with $\tilde f\lvert _V = f$ and $\|\tilde f\|=\|f\|$. In our case let $x\in X$ and let $V=\mathrm{span}(x)$, define $f :V \to\Bbb C$ by extending $f(x)=1$ linearly. Hahn Banach tells you can extend this to a functional defined on all of $X$.